# PIL: Open an image from a POST HTTP request

Tags: python, http, post, python-imaging-library

I want to process an image uploaded to my `SimpleHTTPServer`.

I tried directly feeding `rfile` to `Image.open()`, but this does not work.

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
from PIL import Image

class Handler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):                    
    def do_POST(self):
        img = Image.open(self.rfile)
        # resize, crop, etc.

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I could save the image to the disk and open it normally with PIL, but it doesn't sound like the quickest/cleanest way.

Answer (score 3):

`self.rfile` is a simple file-like wrapper around the `socket` object (see the [`socket.makefile()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) which produces this file object). The wrapper doesn't support seeking, as there only is a stream of data feeding this object, not a random-access region on a disk.

PIL on the other hand, *requires* random access to the whole file (through seeking) as most image formats use different sections in the file to store different information that the PIL objects need access to at different times.

Your only choice is to copy the data from `self.rfile` to a file object that does support seeking. I recommend you use [`tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) for this, as it'll store data in memory until a threshold is reached before moving the data to disk.

You'll need to be careful you only copy only up to the `Content-Length` header bytes into a local file; it is an error to send fewer or more bytes than that. If you don't your server could easily be brought to its knees by sending way bigger POST requests than your disk space can handle.

Perhaps use a `while` loop to copy a buffer across, until `Content-Length` bytes have been reached, or the socket no longer returns data:

```
from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile

def do_POST(self):
    try:
        length = int(self.headers.get('content-length'))
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        # no Content-Length or not a number
        # return error
    if length > SOME_MAXIMUM_LENGTH:
        # return error
        
    with SpooledTemporaryFile() as img_file:
        read = 0
        while read < length:
            buffer = self.rfile.read(1024)
            if not buffer:
                # too short, return error
            img_file.write(buffer)
            read += len(buffer)
        if read > length or self.rfile.read(1):
            # too long, return error

        img_file.seek(0)
        img = Image.open(img_file)
```

If you are accepting a `multipart/form-data` request with this handler, you'll actually have to parse out that specific request type differently. Use the [`cgi.FieldStorage()` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) to handle the parsing, it'll put files into `TemporaryFile` objects for you, directly to disk:

```
from cgi import FieldStorage

def do_POST(self):
    if self.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() == 'multipart/form-data':
        fields = FieldStorage(self.rfile, self.headers, environ={'METHOD': 'POST'})
        imgfile = fields['image_file']  # or whatever exact field name you expect
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm getting an error with `Image.open()`, though: `IOError: cannot identify image file <tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile instance at 0x0000000038C582C8>`

Comment: @EricLeibenguth: right, no filename means no identification. You could parse the `Content-Type` header or use the `imghdr` module to identify the file type first.

Comment: @EricLeibenguth: ah, except PIL will already do the same job, but in this case appears to not recognise the image. Did you upload the image straight as POST or did you use a form POST (so content type `multipart/form-data`)?

Comment: I'm using a form POST for tests, but I'd prefer the server to be agnostic about that... Does it mean I have to exclude some lines from `rfile`?

Comment: @EricLeibenguth: you need to parse the multipart/form-data format and extract your image. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, still some issues with this... 1) `self.headers.get('content-type', '').lower()` returns `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryV7Pd1GA4Fu0erYFa`, so I replaced `==` with `startswith()`. 2) FieldStorage does not seem to parse the fields... `len(fields)` returns `0`

Comment: @EricLeibenguth: I've not before used `FieldStorage` with the `SimpleHTTPServer` hierarchy so perhaps I missed something in the way it parses the socket data; it could be that it too needs to be able to seek. The `cgi` module is rather sparse, looking at the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/cgi.py) may help. Or just switch to Flask and focus on the actual image handling there instead rather than wrestle with HTTP details.